# For Each Loop Question

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I'm having problems understanding a for-each loop. I am familiar w/ the typical structure of a for-each, where there is built in counter and assignment statement to each element. However, in the code below what does the "new" keyword imply? Does it execute only once?

```
for(Integer item : new ArrayList<Integer>(myCollection)){
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + item.intValue());
}
```

Is this equivalent to the following for loop?

```
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < myCollection.size(); ctr++){
    Integer temp = myCollection.get(ctr);
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + item.intValue());
}
```

Comment: I assume you wanted a first.intValue() instead of first,intValue()

Comment: Has no-one mentioned O(n^2) for a `LinkedList<> myCollection`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new` key word implies that it will create a new ArrayList, as if it where anywhere else in code.

The code is basically the same as the following. There is nothing special about using new in a for-each loop.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(myCollection);
for(Integer item : list){
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + item.intValue());
}
```

It is not the same as your alternative loop as the size() changes when you add things to it. I assume you intended for `ctr` and `i` to be the same. It is equivalent to

```
for(int i = 0, size = myCollection.size(); i < size; i++){
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + myCollection.get(i).intValue());
}
```

which I imagine is the same as

```
for(int i = 0, size = myCollection.size(); i < size; i++)
    myCollection.add(first + myCollection.get(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

The first block of code creates a new `ArrayList` of `Integers`, copies the contents of `myCollection` into it, and then iterates over the resulting `ArrayList`.

The copy is needed since the original `myCollection` gets modified inside the loop.

The second block of code isn't equivalent to the first since it adds elements to `myCollection` while iterating over it. Because of this interaction it won't do what you expect and will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Being pedantic, rather than go into an infinite loop, an ArrayList can only have 2^31-1 elements. In fact it will stop at around 1.4 billion as it try to grow to more than this number of elements at that point. ;)  If you used a LinkedList, it would stop at Integer.MAX_VALUE as this is the maximum size() can return.

Answer (score 0):

The two codes that you provide are very similar, but the main difference (the `new` keyword there) is that in the first code you are creating a **copy** of the original list. This is required because inside the loop, you are adding more items to the list, increasing its size. This way, the loop will never exit and eventually you will get of of memory.

The equivalent code using `for(;;)` would be the following:

```
List<Integer> auxList = new ArrayList<Integer>(myCollection);
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < auxList.size(); ctr++){
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + auxList.get(ctr));
}
```

Alternatively you could simply precalculate the size to avoid this captcha:

```
int size = myCollection.size();
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < size; ctr++){
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + myCollection.get(ctr));
}
```

Other than that, the only difference is that the foreach approach uses iterators instead of accessing elements by indexes.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Does it execute only once?

Yes.

> Is this equivalent to the following for loop?

No.  Your loop that follows

1. has three errors (`first,intValue()`, loop index is `ctr` but `myCollection.get(i)`, you fetch into `temp` and leave `item` undefined),
2. iterates over `myCollection`, adding to it, while continually checking against a growing size, and so it
3. does not terminate (`size()` is growing), except that it
4. will eventually throw an `OutOfMemoryError`.

It is, however, equivalent to this

```
for (int i = 0, n = myCollections.size(); i < n; i++) {
    Integer item = myCollection.get(i);
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + item.intValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop

```
for(Integer item : new ArrayList<Integer>(myCollection)){
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + item.intValue());
}
```

is compiled to the same code (modulo variable names) as

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = new ArrayList<Integer>(myCollection).iterator();
     it.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer item = iterator.next();
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + item.intValue());
}
```

If the size of `myCollection` would not change (and myCollection is a `List`), then this would be the same (only less efficient for creating a temporary list) as

```
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < myCollection.size(); ctr++){
    Integer temp = myCollection.get(i);
    myCollection.add(first.intValue() + temp.intValue());
}
```

... but you are changing `myCollection` inside the loop, so this second loop would never reach the end (assuming at least one element is in it).

So your ArrayList helps having your loop well-behaved.